# What does "defy repetition" mean here?

Tags: verbs

In the following paragraph, what does "defy repetition" mean? I know what ***defy*** and ***repetition*** mean, but don't know what it means when they connnected. Thanks.

> You can create a database under the assumption that SQL looks after
>   all the problems of concurrency. It will probably work fine under test
>   conditions: Then, in the production environment, it starts losing data
>   in subtle ways ***that defy repetition***. It is every Database Developer's
>   nightmare. In an excerpt from his acclaimed book, Alex explains why it
>   happens, and how you can avoid such problems.

Comment: It's a cliche but it means in a non-reproducible way.

Comment: Non recoverable data , once lost that is.

Comment: It [**defies belief**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22defies+belief%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) that this question might be considered On Topic on ELU. Perhaps [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Nah. In any credible environment the "lost" data would almost certainly be "recoverable". What *can't* be repeated is the exact circumstances that caused that *particular* data to be lost, which poses problems for the technician trying to debug the precise cause and thereby correct the underlying fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the error it causes cannot be reliably reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Defy means that it mockingly challenges repetition.

Now repetition is not usually mocked in this way, except in an IT-environment where just about the first thing someone does when a bug is reported, is to reproduce, or repeat it.

Normally, "cannot reproduce" can be a valid reason to close a call, and not to spend more time on finding the actual error - unless it causes real problems.

Some errors are so seemingly randomly happening and so seemingly impossible to reproduce that they can drive people mad trying to figure out what is wrong, and where. If an bug cannot be reproduced by the developers, but it keeps happening in production, we usually blame the user. (Just kidding there; we *always* blame the user anyway!)

Bugs that are really good at being there one moment, but being nowhere when you try to look for them are also called **Heisenbugs**.